# Jquery: Remove " " value from array without using each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My sample array is below, I want to remove key 1 which is having "" value.

```
var a=[
       0: "349,602,317,805,887,810,863,657,665,865,102,624,659,636",
       1: ""
      ]
```

When i was browsing i found solution like use $.each()  and keep condition. But i want to filter in single shot using jquery. Any function is there !!!!

Comment: It should be {object} notation, not [array].

Comment: Or rather : this notation is invalid. Arrays do not take indexes. You mixed up an object and an array to get to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a.filter( Boolean );
```

will do the trick here! Since `Array.prototype.filter` is a standard Array method you don't need any 3rd party library.

What happens is, we call the `.filter()` method with the `Boolean` constructor method, which, only returns a truthy value if the value that gets passed in really is *truthy* for Javascript. Excludes:

- Empty String ("")
- 0
- false
- undefined
- NaN
- null

Comment: can i know hot boolean is filtering "" pls

Comment: I actually just realized that you code is not valid. Are you sure you posted the correct code ?

Comment: you should update the question with the actual input code data, otherwise this gets very confusing.

Comment: It works on arrays, not objects (the OP's notation is invalid in the original post). +1 for the very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `delete`- operator. Its not the index.

```
delete a[key];
```

Comment: Yeah but the "" is not necessarily in position 1... that would be too easy :)

Comment: you can just set a key . the 1 isnt the index, its a key. @JeremyThille

Comment: Still, to find the ones with value "", you would need a loop

Comment: Yes, but in his question he wanted to remove the key. i thought it isnt depending on the value.

Comment: " " its not a key. You have to take the keys from the object. Like in this case 0 and 1

Comment: `delete key` works on objects, OP it talking about arrays (he's using an invalid notation that makes his array look like an object)

Comment: Its also not sure if he know there is a object format..  he has just to change the [ to {

Answer (score 0):

you use use something like this

```
var index = a.indexOf("");
if(index >=0)
 a.splice(index,1);
```